# Generating new id for each request

Tags: ember.js

My app communicates with the server in json rpc format - and each request from the client needs to have a new id generated by the client. jsonrpc specs example:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subtract", "params": [42, 23], "id": 1}
```

and the next request would have an id=2 and so on.

I read that having global variables in ember is not recommended, so I guess I should keep the id in the application route, and have a function that sets id to be id++ and return the new value. However, I dont know how to access this function as I keep getting errors on stuff like

```
    data["id"] = Addapp.ApplicationRoute.getNewJRId();
```

where the ApplicationRoute is undefined...

My questions are: Would this be a proper approach?

I do this, how?

Comment: Why not use uuid or guid?

Comment: Have you considered generating your new ID function with it's encapsulated scope: `Addapp.ApplicationRoute.getNewJRId = (function(){ var current = 1; return function(){ return current++; }})();`

Comment: Agreed on @torazaburo's comment. Stated another way, is there a true requirement that your ids be sequential, or is it enough that they would be unique? You can achieve uniqueness without necessarily keeping anything global. `new Date().getTime()` is enough for that.

Comment: I would say that you should keep the variable in whatever class communicates with your server. If that's not possible, global variables aren't the end of the world. Every app has one or two of them.